# Editing XML files with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to edit some XML values via my PHP admin panel what do I have to do?

I have tried DOMDocument from PHP but it didn't help me ( I AM USING PHP 5 )

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tns:database xmlns:tns="http://www.iw.com/sns/platform/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ItemSpec id="57000" type="1" rewardid="232900" function_on="1" popup="1"/>
</tns:database>
```

Let's say I want to edit the rewardid value for id="57000" but I couldn't do it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a string source for the XML rather than a file ( though it is just as easy to do the following )

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <tns:database xmlns:tns="http://www.iw.com/sns/platform/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <ItemSpec id="57000" type="1" rewardid="232900" function_on="1" popup="1"/>
        </tns:database>';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//ItemSpec[@id="57000"]');

if( $col->length > 0 ){
    $attr=$dom->createAttribute('rewardid');
    $attr->nodeValue='banana';

    $node=$col->item(0);
    $node->removeAttribute('rewardid');
    $node->appendChild( $attr );
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

If it is a file source then `$dom->load( $file )` and at the end `$dom->save( $file )` etc

To edit an existing attribute,rather than create a new one as above and append it you can simply do:

```
$node->setAttribute('rewardid','banana'); //etc
```

Comment: `setAttribute()` will create an attribute if it does not exists. So you can simplify the source to: https://3v4l.org/UZq4H